# GLSL blur effect on non textured rect

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader, blur

I'm trying to get a blur working using a glsl shader.
I have looked for it on the internet but found only found fragment shaders with a texture input.
What if I want to blur things without a texture though? How would I do that?

Should look something like that:

[image: img]

Comment: Can you be more specific about the desired effect? I picture would help.

Comment: edited the post

Comment: It looks like you may want a general post-processing blur. This may be a good starting resource: https://learnopengl.com/In-Practice/2D-Game/Postprocessing

Comment: looks like simple blur ... google convolution blur/smooth filters in case its Gaussian blur see https://stackoverflow.com/a/64845819/2521214

Comment: @Spektre the problem is that is has a uniform sampler2D texture and I don't know what to put in there as I don't have any texture... what would be the fix for that?

Comment: @RobinCirex render to textute or use `glReadPixels` in first pass and then in second pass blur it using the texture obtained from first pass

Comment: @RobinCirex where/how is your image located/stored?

Comment: @YakovGalka i don't have an image

Comment: @Spektre okay, could you give an example of how to use that?

Comment: @RobinCirex huh? 'blur' is an operation that's applied to images. In fact you just attached a sample image to your question above. This image must be stored somewhere in your system's memory -- my question is where. If it's not in a texture, is it in a framebuffer? system RAM? file?

Comment: @YakovGalka Oh, sorry, I misunderstood that. It's in a framebuffer, yes

Comment: @RobinCirex see [OpenGL Scale Single Pixel Line](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43654398/2521214) for 2 pass rendering example using `glReadPixels` if you want speed and have capable HW use [FBO and render to texture](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43930271/2521214) instead ...

Answer (score 1):

A shader cannot read from a framebuffer directly. Textures are the primary way for reading images from within a shader (there's also [SSBO](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Shader_Storage_Buffer_Object) but I wouldn't suggest using it here).

Thus, put it short, the answer to "how to blur an image without a texture" is: create a texture! You can either copy your image from the framebuffer to the texture with `glCopyTextureSubImage2D`; or, even better, render to an [off-screen FBO](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Framebuffer_Object) backed by the texture from the start.

**EDIT:** example of copying from current framebuffer to a texture (in C):

```
GLuint tex;
glCreateTextures(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 1, &tex);
glTextureStorage2D(tex, 1 /*levels*/, GL_SRGB8_ALPHA8, width, height);
glCopyTextureSubImage2D(tex, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, width, height);
// tex now contains the content of framebuffer
```

Comment: could you give an example of how to use glCopyTexSubImage2D and store the data? Because it doesn't return anything. Btw I'm doing this in Java, probably should've mentioned that before.

Comment: Sorry to necro this but I saw an unanswered comment and couldn't resist. glCreateTextures in C takes a pointer to the tex value (hence the ampersand) and will just write into that value in-place. This mitigates the need for return values, though I can see how it would be confusing to non-C programmers, seeing as it looks like an input parameter, and the function has no return type. I haven't touched Java in years so can't say how it would work in that. It also depends on the library. If your version of glCreateTextures returns a value, you'll want to capture it.

Comment: @Logix OP was asking about an example of using glCopyTexSubImage2D, not glCreateTextures. And their comment was answered in the the EDIT to the answer above.

Comment: I think you've missed the point. I was answering @RobinCirex' query in the comment above.